# Installing OS on hard drive, then moving hard drive to another machine

Tags: linux, installation, drivers, operating-systems

I have an old desktop which doesn't have a working CD/DVD. I want to install Linux on it in the simplest way possible.

I'm thinking I could solve this problem by removing the hard drive temporarily to another machine, installing the OS there, then moving it back. My concern is that, as far as I know (correct me if I'm wrong), during the installation, the OS detects the hardware and installs drivers accordingly. So if I move the hard drive to another machine, I might run into problems.

As I said, I'm not 100% sure what I'm saying is accurate. Any input on this?

Comment: USB boot may be possible. Could you tell us what machine it is? Or check?

Comment: @Simon Sheehan, Good point. Problem is, because it's an old machine, I doubt the BIOS will support USB boot. (to answer your question about the type of machine, it's a no brand assembly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are not wrong. Unless these computers are in the same hardware configuration it will not work correctly (it probably will boot up but this is not a proper way).

If you cant mount ODD drive on old computer, you could boot up linux from USB memory. Chceck this website

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/

Answer (score 1):

Cant you temporarily move a dvd player TO the old machine rather than the other way around?

Comment: Aslund +1, this is better way :D